# Mirrored UVs not fixed by inverting scale - how to fix

Tags: texturing, uv

Making a packaging box, i started out with a flat plane and used a reference image of the packaging dielines to create cuts and folds. I've proceeded to fold the box just as you would in real life ( no scaling throughout ) but when i come to apply the image texture i can see that the UV's are mirrored. I've tried inverting the scale value in the mapping node, but that throws the texture out completely.

I feel like im missing something super obvious here - please help! Thank you[image: mirrored texture box]

Edit: Added the Blend File

[image]

Comment: in the UV Editor, select the inverted UV and scale with a SX-1? Or please share your file so we can give a try, don't forget to pack your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all these side faces in the 3D view, it will select them in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

Then in the *UV Editor* press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>, it will mirror all these faces and fix your problem:

[image]

Comment: Moonboots my hero